# Learning c# with VisualStudio. When open new console app doesnt have main or class args as in tutorial videos.Are these args still necessary in c# 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am using the latest version of windows Visual Studio and I think C# 10. I'm not even familiar with what these arguments mean, but in every tutorial video I've watched (the most recent being 6 months old), as soon as they open a new console application it includes these arguments. Are they necessary for this type of beginner code? Should I learn and include them anyway?

Comment: You don't have to use, and you can use if you want. Here is the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements

Answer (score 1):

[C# uses top level statements now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates), so the `Main` function isn't necessary anymore. You can just write code directly at the top of the file and it will act exactly as though it was inside of the old `Main` function.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. The omitted main method is a feature starting in C# 9.0 and is described here [Main() and command-line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line).

Comment: Thank you.  Would you recommend that I still use the main method in my programs?  Will they be important to learn later?

Comment: @JonathanGoode Well, it depends. Using top level statements the compiler creates automaticaly a main method, so IMO you should also learn using the main method. It could also be important if you're dealing with projects using a main method. But for new projects I would use top level statements.